# What is meant by block address size in File system?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

Block address size = 4 B. Does it mean that there are total 2^4 = 16 blocks in the disk or something else?

Comment: the devil in detail, so can you told as what type of file system  are u talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most disks cannot perform reads and writes at byte granularity and instead perform reads and writes in units of **sectors**, which today are almost universally 512 bytes each.

File systems actually allocate and use disk storage in units of **blocks** 
Be wary of the distinction between the two terms: **sector** size is a property of the **disk hardware**, whereas `block` size is an aspect of the `operating system` using the disk. A file system's block size must be a multiple of the sector size of the underlying disk.